# Google Maps Geometry Library: how do I create a marker that is in a state of being dragged

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, draggable

My intention is to split a polyline (with two coordinates) in two on *dragstart* event.

What is happening in code below:

1. Polyline is waiting for dragstart
2. When user starts dragging Polyline, two new Polylines and a Marker in between them replace the old Polyline
3. Dragging stops at current mouse location without releasing mouse

Actual intention:

In step 3, dragging continues, but dragged element is the new Marker and not the removed Polyline.

How do I transfer "dragging" from Polyline to a Marker?

```js
const path = new google.maps.MVCArray([
  new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
  new google.maps.LatLng(10, 10),
])

const polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
  map,
  path,
  draggable: true
})

let marker, newPolylineA, newPolylineB

const dragstartListener = polyline.addListener('dragstart', ({ latLng }) => {
  google.maps.event.removeListener(dragstartListener)
  polyline.setMap(null)

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map,
    position: latLng,
    draggable: true,
  })

  newPolylineA = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map,
    path: [ path.getAt(0), latLng ],
  })

  newPolylineB = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map,
    path: [ latLng, path.getAt(1) ],
  })
})
```

Comment: Why don't you just add a draggable marker and bind it to the new vertex of the polyline?

Comment: I am creating new Marker and binding Polylines to it. But because of UX reasons (1 click is better than 2 clicks for single action), I want to change dragging target from initial Polyline to the new Marker.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by hiding original Polyline with strokeOpacity and using drag and dragend events.

It's not actual swap of drag targets, but it at least imitates the result.

```js
const coordinateA = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0)
const coordinateB = new google.maps.LatLng(10, 10)
const path = new google.maps.MVCArray([
  coordinateA,
  coordinateB,
])

const polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
  map,
  path,
  draggable: true
})

let marker, newPolylineA, newPolylineB

const dragstartListener = polyline.addListener('dragstart', ({ latLng }) => {
  polyline.setOptions({
    strokeOpacity: 0
  })

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map,
    position: latLng,
    draggable: true,
  })

  newPolylineA = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map,
    path: [ path.getAt(0), latLng ],
  })

  newPolylineB = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map,
    path: [ latLng, path.getAt(1) ],
  })

  google.maps.event.removeListener(dragstartListener)
})

const dragListener = polyline.addListener('drag', ({ latLng }) => {
  marker.setPosition(latLng)  
  newPolylineA.setPath([ coordinateA, latLng ])
  newPolylineB.setPath([ latLng, coordinateB ])
})

const dragendListener = polyline.addListener('dragend', ({ latLng }) => {
  google.maps.event.removeListener(dragendListener)
  google.maps.event.removeListener(dragListener)

  marker.setPosition(latLng)  
  newPolylineA.setPath([ coordinateA, latLng ])
  newPolylineB.setPath([ latLng, coordinateB ])

  polyline.setMap(null)
})
```